# ui-router not rendering template MVC5

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, asp.net-mvc-5

I am unable to get the most basic of Angular UI-Router setups to work correctly.

I just want a hard coded template to render for now, then diagnose getting a .html file to load. I am using MVC5 for my project I will break up the files below, but I will skip some of the obvious stuff... if I need to include it, I will. (By obvious I mean where I'm putting in the scripts/css, head tags, html tags, all that stuff.)

**Index.cshtml**

```
<div ui-view="test"></div>
```

**_Layout.cshtml**

```
@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title></title>
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
</head>
<body ng-app="myApp">
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
    <div class="container">
        @RenderBody()
    </div>
    @Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/Apps")
</body>
</html>
```

**myApp.js**

```
(function () {
    "use strict";
    var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ["ui.router"]);
    myApp.config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
        $stateProvider
          .state('home', {
              url: '/',
              views: {
                  "test@home": {
                      template:"<h1>Test</h1>"
                  }
              }
          })

        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/")
    }]);
})();
```

Yet when I navigate to my my site... it's just a blank white page?
No console errors or anything...

I tried adding a:

```
<a ui-sref="test"></a>
```

and that just threw an error along the lines of:

```
Error: Could not resolve 'test' from state ''
```

So I'm lost... any advice would be awesome!

Comment: you have no `test` state shown in router ... also likely getting error thrown in console since `doranApp` is undefined ...have you looked in dev tools console?

Comment: That was my typo. I corrected it to reflect "myApp" appropriately. I have been checking dev tools and when I click my ui-sref I get an error - outside of that? Nothing... for kicks I added a button with an ng-click function all in line just to make sure angular itself was working and it acted correctly... so I know angular is getting in there, and it isn't complaining about ui-router.

Comment: I would recommend trying to remove the absolute naming "test@home"

Comment: I tried changing it to:  views: {"test": { template: "<h1>Test</h1>" } } and I tried leaving it unnamed and neither solution worked. Both brought up a blank screen?

Comment: Why are you using AngularJS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First change your "test@home" view for "test-home".

then change the name of your view as it is specify on the script:

From:

```
<div ui-view="test"></div>
```

To:

```
<div ui-view="test-home"></div>
```

The right code:

```
     var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ["ui.router"]);
     myApp.config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/home");

        $stateProvider
          .state('home', {
             url: '/home',
             views: {
                "test-home": {
                   template: "<h1>Home</h1>"
                }
             }
          }).state('test', {
             url: '/test',
             views: {
                "test-home": {
                   template: "<h1>teste</h1>"
                }
             }
          });

     }]);
```